# fwrite not working correctly, and writing duplicated information

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I'm a beginner with PHP and i'm having some problems with the fwrite function.
I need that the information be writed in one line and after the ofter user use the form, the information of the form go for the other line.

Example:

USER 1:
FORM
name: john
email: john@gmail.com

USER 2:
FORM
name: Bonnie
email: bonnie@gmail.com

FILE:
Name:Jhon|email:john@gmail.com
Name:Bonnie|email:bonnie@gmail.com

The form is working perfectly, the problem is in the fwrite function.
I trying like this

```
$arquivo = fopen("info.txt", "a+");
        $txt = $nome."|".$data."|".$cidade."|".$email."|".$senha."\r\n";
        fwrite($arquivo, $txt);
        fclose($arquivo);
```

In this way, every time that the page is reloaded, the previous data is duplicated.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use JSON, it has already all the tools for the string parsing... just a hint

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say in your question the function and form work well but your code is triggered on page refresh. What you need to do is to bind your write function to an action.

There are 2 ways to do that.

1) **Using only php and Html** is to create a `<form>` and put an action which will point to your php file that your write function exists. You will need a submit button which i assume you already have since your form is working fine. That way everytime you submit your form you will trigger your function and not in page refresh.

```
<form action="your_php_file.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Just a basic exampl you extend it to what you want to have. Just make sure in your php file you use the `$_POST['name']`  & `$_POST['email']`  to retrieve the values of your input fields.

2) **Using Html , Javacript + ajax , php**

In this one you don't need a form but you need to get the values of your elements using **javascript selectors**. After that you make an ajax call using an event `onClick` and send all your html values to your php file and retrieve the values the same way. In this case your page won't refresh.